# Change 'home' link in breadcrumb to specific page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, edit, breadcrumbs

I'm using the Avada theme, and trying to edit the breadcrumb Home link. It has to refer to another link. The wordpress given code isn't working. Someone got any idea?

Using original given wordpress code isn't working. The exact URL isn't doing the job, nor is the return get_permalink( $shop_page_id ).

Code below isn't working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url', 'woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url' );
function woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url() {
    $shop_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ); 
    return get_permalink( $shop_page_id ) ;
}
```

Hope anyone can help me to get this done using the Avada theme?

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce? Because, you are using the WC hook. Are you using Yoast or something else to handle your breadcrumbs?

Comment: Hi,  yes I'm using Woocommece. I have Yoast installed but didn't edit any settings so far.